# Why can't I execute msdb.dbo.send_dbmail from a stored procedure being executed in a job?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, sql-server-agent, sp-send-dbmail, sql-job

I have a job scheduled to run on my server. That job executes a stored procedure. Inside that stored procedure I am executing msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail. When I execute the stored procedure logged in as an admin it runs fine. When the job runs though, it fails with the following error:

`Executed as user: AD\sql_server. Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259. [SQLSTATE 42000](Error 22050). The step failed.`

I have tried modifying the stored procedure and adding in `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER`. When I do this the stored procedure fails with the following error:

`Executed as user: AD\sql_server. The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000](Error 229). The step failed.`

What do I need to do to be able to execute a stored procedure in a job that executes msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` is not going to solve your problem.

You may have to add the user as a part of the built in database mail role with something like:

```
USE msdb;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'DatabaseMailUserRole', 'AD\sql_server'
```

Check out [this post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic686387-359-1.aspx).